# How do I set marks in Emacs à la Vim?

Tags: emacs, bookmarks

I'd like to be able to set multiple marks in Emacs like Vim does. In Vim you might press <kbd>m</kbd>  <kbd>b</kbd> and that would set a mark at that line in the file. Later pressing <kbd>'</kbd> <kbd>b</kbd> will move your cursor back to that line. You can make multiple marks with <kbd>m</kbd><kbd>{a-zA-Z}</kbd>. Is there a way to have multiple marks like this in Emacs?

Comment: You want [evil-mode](https://github.com/emacs-evil/evil) ☺

Answer (score 17, accepted):

You can use what Emacs calls `registers`.  The  [documentation](http://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_mono/emacs.html#Registers) explains them better than I can.

Comment: Thanks. For a bonus multiplier, do you know of any way/plugin to highlight marked lines?

Comment: No, no way that I know of.  There are commands, such as `highlight-phrase` and `highlight-regexp`, which may be useful, but nothing like `highlight-register` in the standard build.

Comment: @MDCore: I've been using Emacs for donkeys years, but still learn something new every time I check this tag on SO.  Thanks.

Answer (score 35):

From [Emacs documentation](http://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_mono/emacs.html#RegPos) :

<kbd>C-x</kbd> <kbd>r</kbd> <kbd>SPC</kbd> **r**

- Record the position of point and the current buffer in register r (point-to-register).

<kbd>C-x</kbd> <kbd>r</kbd> <kbd>j</kbd> **r**

- Jump to the position and buffer saved in register r (jump-to-register).

**But if you want your positions to persist automatically from one Emacs session to the next, you should use [Bookmarks](http://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_mono/emacs.html#Bookmarks)** :

<kbd>C-x</kbd> <kbd>r</kbd> <kbd>m</kbd> <kbd>RET</kbd>

- Set the bookmark for the visited file, at point.

<kbd>C-x</kbd> <kbd>r</kbd> <kbd>m</kbd> **bookmark** <kbd>RET</kbd>

- Set the bookmark named **bookmark** at point (bookmark-set).

<kbd>C-x</kbd> <kbd>r</kbd> <kbd>b</kbd> **bookmark** <kbd>RET</kbd>

- Jump to the bookmark named **bookmark** (bookmark-jump).

<kbd>C-x</kbd> <kbd>r</kbd> <kbd>l</kbd>

- List all bookmarks (list-bookmarks).

<kbd>M-x</kbd> <kbd>bookmark-save</kbd>

- Save all the current bookmark values in the default bookmark file.

Answer (score 6):

Try the mark ring for quick marks:

<kbd>C-space</kbd>

Make a mark at current position; also, add position to mark ring.

<kbd>C-x</kbd><kbd>C-x</kbd>

Jump back to previous mark.

<kbd>C-U</kbd><kbd>C-space</kbd>

Cycle through marks in the mark ring.

I used Vim for a decade before switching to Emacs a few years ago, and while the registers and bookmarks looked good at first, the mark ring is what I actually end up using 90% of the time. Usually I just use the C-space, C-x C-x, but cycling works, too.

Btw, realize that doing large non-arrow key movements like M-v will often add a mark to the mark ring. Just practice these key combos and you'll likely find them sufficient for most tasks.

Radix already did a good job explaining the registers and bookmarks, and those are useful for locations in files that will be referred to often or need annotation.

Comment: To avoid transient mark being activated when jumping (C-x C-x), use prefix argument (C-u C-x C-x).

Answer (score 5):

Vanilla Emacs makes you specify a name for each bookmark.  What you want, it sounds like, is a quick way to create bookmarks without naming them -- just hit a key.  You want [autonamed bookmarks](http://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/BookmarkPlus#AutonamedBookmarks), available with [***Bookmark+***](http://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/BookmarkPlus).  You can even have them be automatically [highlighted](http://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/BookmarkPlus#HighlightingAutomatically), if you like (the fringe or the line).

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at this: http://www.cs.utah.edu/dept/old/texinfo/emacs18/emacs_13.html

Comment: Yeah I'm looking for random access to my marks. That mark ring is a stack.